Getting exception when adding row in column
I have the following code in my build method in my stateless widget:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [drawPieChart(), Text('wfwefwef')],
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('-Income-'),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            ),
            Expanded(child: listOfIncomeExpenditure()),
            Container(
              child: Text('-Expense-'),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            ),
            Expanded(child: listOfExpenseExpenditure())
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          key: const Key('counterView_increment_floatingActionButton'),
          child: const Icon(Icons.currency_pound),
          onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext _) =>
                expenditureForm.showAddExpenditureDialogBox(context, false),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

And the drawPieChart() method contains the following:
BlocBuilder<FinanceBloc, FinanceState> drawPieChart() {
return BlocBuilder(
    buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
        previous != current && current is FinanceSavedState,
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is FinanceSavedState) {
        
        ..Getting information and creating an array of `PieChartSectionData` here

        return PieChart(
          //This piechartdata array takes in an array of of pie chart points
          PieChartData(sections: using the array here),
        );
      } else {
        return Text(
            'The graph will present itself when you add an expenditure!');
      }
    });
}

So the above does render fine without the Row and having Expanded(child: drawPieChart() explicitly in the Column. although I want to now change the layout of the page. Because I'm using a column, each widget is obviously stacked below the other.
I want to essentially add a Row as the first child of the children array in the Column widget so i can add a Widget (ideally a Text widget) side by side to the PieChart but when I do add a Row widget, I get the stacktrace following:

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderPieChart object was given an infinite size during layout.
This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderFlex#aaf9e relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
creator: Column ← KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#63f19] ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ←
LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← _ActionsScope ← Actions ←
AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#425ec ink
renderer] ← ⋯
parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=500.0, 0.0<=h<=757.0)
size: MISSING
direction: vertical
mainAxisAlignment: start
mainAxisSize: max
crossAxisAlignment: center
verticalDirection: down
The constraints that applied to the RenderPieChart were:
BoxConstraints(w=500.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was:
Size(500.0, Infinity)
See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
PieChart

Is there any way I can fix this? I am using fl_chart for the PieChart widget v0.69.0. An overview of the libary can be found here.

Show the code you're using when you put in your Row (i.e. show the code actually generating the error). You likely need another Expanded somewhere to provide proper constraints on the PieChart.

@ChristopherMoore thanks, I have added the code

You need to wrap the PieChart with Expanded widget or SizedBox if you need the parent widget take specified size:
return Expanded( // or SizedBox
  child: BlocBuilder<FinanceBloc, FinanceState>(
    buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
        previous != current && current is FinanceSavedState,
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is FinanceSavedState) {
        // Getting information and creating an array of `PieChartSectionData` here
        final pieChartSections = [
          // Add your PieChartSectionData objects here
        ];

        return PieChart(
          PieChartData(
            sections: pieChartSections, // Using the array here
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return Text(
          'The graph will present itself when you add an expenditure!',
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);


